# Web-scraping a simulator

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all the data inside this loan simulator:

https://m-pt-funnel.younited-credit.com/initialproposal

For example, I need to get all the TAEG values depending on the loan amount and time ("meses")

I was searching for a json file in this website so that I can use get/post functions to extract the info but I was unable to find the json.

Further than the TAEG information, I would also like to get the monthly payment (the numbers in orange), the number of months to pay (number of "meses" at the right) and the "MONTANTE TOTAL DEVIDO" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Why do you think it supports a REST API?

Comment: @doctorlove I've made something similar to other simulators, but I understand that this one is different

Answer (score 1):

If there is no API, you could use Selenium with Chrome driver and copy the fields by referencing the Xpath, you could select fields and click calculate then use the "wait" function to then grab the results and store in a table or log. you will need to download chrome driver though/.

example on first value:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://m-pt-funnel.younited-credit.com/initialproposal')
time.sleep(5)
rtn_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='"'wrappApp'"']/div/div/yuc-initial-proposal-step/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/yuc-commercial-offer/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[2]/label")
rtn = [x.text for x in rtn_element]
# print out all info on RTN
print('RTN:')
print(rtn, '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jon but the result is empty ```python RTN:
[]  ```